# I can't see the items under a specific office? When i check the dropdown it has no options

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, jsx, react-hook-form

I want when

- offices === Building Management Office is picked it will show in the items
  **Spaling Basketball, Mikasa Volleyball**,
- when offices === Information Technology Resource Office === **Nikon D300,Profoto B10 Plus Strobe Lights**
- when offices === Engineering and Science Laboratory Office === **Pyrex Beaker,Pyrex Graduated Cycliner**

but in my code, there is no options shown i dont know if my logic is wrong can anyone help me

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { AdapterDayjs } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs";
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider";
import { DatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Select from "react-select";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import InnerContainer from "./InnerContainer";

const sample_bmo_item = [
  {
    label: "Spalding Basketball",
    value: "101",
  },
  {
    label: "Mikasa Volleyball",
    value: "102",
  },
];

const sample_itro_item = [
  {
    label: "Nikon D300",
    value: "201",
  },
  {
    label: "Profoto B10 Plus Strobe Lights",
    value: "202",
  },
];

const sample_eslo_item = [
  {
    label: "Pyrex Beaker",
    value: "301",
  },
  {
    label: "Pyrex Graduated Cycliner",
    value: "302",
  },
];

const offices = [
  { label: "Building Management Office", value: "Building Management Office" },
  {
    label: "Information Technology and Resource Office",
    value: "Information Technology and Resource Office",
  },
  {
    label: "Engineering and Science Laboratory Office",
    value: "Engineering and Science Laboratory Office",
  },
];

const purposes = [
  {
    label: "Academic Purposes - Assignment & Activities",
    value: "Academic Purposes - Assignment & Activities",
  },
  { label: "Organization Purposes", value: "Organization Purposes" },
  {
    label: "Academic Purposes - Midterms & Finals",
    value: "Academic Purposes - Midterms & Finals",
  },
  { label: "Special Events", value: "Special Events" },
  { label: "Others", value: "Others" },
];

const endorser = [
  {
    label: "Ms. -",
    value: "Ms. -",
  },
  {
    label: "Sir. -",
    value: "Sir. -",
  },
  {
    label: "Ms. -",
    value: "Ms. -",
  },
  {
    label: "Ms. -",
    value: "Ms. -",
  },
  {
    label: "Ms. -",
    value: "Ms. -",
  },
];

const BorrowForm = () => {
  const { control, handleSubmit, setValue, watch } = useForm();
  const selectedPurpose = watch("purposes");
  const selectedOffice = watch("offices");

  const selectedItems =
    selectedOffice === "Building Management Office"
      ? sample_bmo_item
      : selectedOffice === "Information Technology and Resource Office"
      ? sample_itro_item
      : selectedOffice === "Engineering and Science Laboratory Office"
      ? sample_eslo_item
      : [];

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log("submit hit with data:", data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("selected purpose changed to:", selectedPurpose);
  }, [selectedPurpose]);

  return (
    <InnerContainer>
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <div className="borrowing-transaction">
          <Typography>Borrowing Information</Typography>
          <div className="endorser">
            <Typography>Endorsed By</Typography>
            <Controller
              name="endorser"
              control={control}
              render={({ field }) => <Select {...field} options={endorser} />}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="office">
            <Typography>Office</Typography>
            <Controller
              name="offices"
              control={control}
              defaultValue=""
              render={({ field }) => <Select {...field} options={offices} />}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="purposes">
            <Typography>Purpose</Typography>
            <Controller
              name="purposes"
              control={control}
              render={({ field }) => (
                <Select
                  options={purposes}
                  {...field}
                  value={purposes.find((c) => c.value === field.value?.value)}
                />
              )}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="specific-purpose">
            <Typography>Specific Purpose</Typography>
            <TextField
              label="Enter Specific Purpose"
              variant="filled"
              fullWidth
              style={{
                backgroundColor:
                  selectedPurpose?.value === "Others" ? "white" : "yellow",
              }}
              disabled={selectedPurpose?.value === "Others" ? false : true}
              onChange={(e) =>
                setValue("specificPurposeInputText", e.target.value)
              }
            />
          </div>

          <div className="date-pickers">
            <Typography>Starting Date</Typography>
            <Controller
              control={control}
              name="start-date"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <DatePicker
                  placeholderText="Select date"
                  onChange={(date) => field.onChange(date)}
                  selected={field.value}
                />
              )}
            />

            <Typography>Returning Date</Typography>
            <Controller
              control={control}
              name="return-date"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <DatePicker
                  placeholderText="Select date"
                  onChange={(date) => field.onChange(date)}
                  selected={field.value}
                />
              )}
            />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="items">
          <Typography>Item</Typography>
          <div className="oneby">
            <div className="equipment-name">
              <Typography>Equipment Name</Typography>
              <Controller
                control={control}
                name="equipmentName"
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <Select
                    {...field}
                    options={selectedItems}
                  />
                )}
              />
            </div>

            <div className="start-date-item">
              <Typography>Starting Date</Typography>
              <Controller
                control={control}
                name="return-date-item"
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <DatePicker
                    placeholderText="Select date"
                    onChange={(date) => field.onChange(date)}
                    selected={field.value}
                  />
                )}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="return-date-item">
              <Typography>Returning Date</Typography>
              <Controller
                control={control}
                name="return-date"
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <DatePicker
                    placeholderText="Select date"
                    onChange={(date) => field.onChange(date)}
                    selected={field.value}
                  />
                )}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="quantity"></div>
            <Typography>Quantity</Typography>
            <TextField
              id="outlined-number"
              label="Number"
              type="number"
              InputLabelProps={{
                shrink: true,
              }}
            />
          </div>
        </div>

        <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </form>
    </LocalizationProvider>
    </InnerContainer>
  );
};

export default BorrowForm;
```

I tried selected the selectedItems, since I formatted when user picks a specific office it will show there items only

```
<div className="items">
          <Typography>Item</Typography>
          <div className="oneby">
            <div className="equipment-name">
              <Typography>Equipment Name</Typography>
              <Controller
                control={control}
                name="equipmentName"
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <Select
                    {...field}
                    options={selectedItems}
                  />
                )}
              />
            </div>

            <div className="start-date-item">
              <Typography>Starting Date</Typography>
              <Controller
                control={control}
                name="return-date-item"
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <DatePicker
                    placeholderText="Select date"
                    onChange={(date) => field.onChange(date)}
                    selected={field.value}
                  />
                )}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="return-date-item">
              <Typography>Returning Date</Typography>
              <Controller
                control={control}
                name="return-date"
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <DatePicker
                    placeholderText="Select date"
                    onChange={(date) => field.onChange(date)}
                    selected={field.value}
                  />
                )}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="quantity"></div>
            <Typography>Quantity</Typography>
            <TextField
              id="outlined-number"
              label="Number"
              type="number"
              InputLabelProps={{
                shrink: true,
              }}
            />
          </div>
```

Comment: That `selectedItems` nested ternary is a code smell.  Start by writing that in another way.

Comment: @jmargolisvt can you give me an example on how to write or where to start? that would be a great help

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-nested-ternary

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question is that you are unable to view a `Select` element with options for the 'Office' selection.

If that is the case you may have to render the 'Office' `Select` a bit differently. You can read more about [Controller](https://www.react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller/) from the docs, and may also be interested in a usage [example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-select-with-react-hook-form-sc2xz?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A11%2C3).

Try refactoring your 'Office' field in the component by changing the following lines:

```
        <div className="office">
            <Typography>Office</Typography>
            <Controller
              name="offices"
              control={control}
              defaultValue=""
              render={({ onChange, value}) => (
                         <Select 
                             options={offices} 
                             value={offices.find((off) => off.value === value)}
                             onChange={(val) => onChange(val.value)}
                         />
                     })
            />
          </div>
```

Comment: Ill try rendering the Controller from office differently, but your example helped me a lot thank you!